# meaning of "catch"

Tags: meaning

I was wondering what "catch it" means. I guess it means "deal with it" but there are no such meanings in dictionaries. The sentence comes at the beginning of the NBC NEWS clip, https://archive.org/download/KNTV_20211216_023000_NBC_Nightly_News_With_Lester_Holt/KNTV_20211216_023000_NBC_Nightly_News_With_Lester_Holt.mp4?t=1245/1305&exact=1&ignore=x.mp4

> A simple blood test, researchers believe, could revolutionize the way
> cancer is detected and **catch it** earlier.

Comment: It's a figurative extension from ***catch = trap, pin down*** (so it can be ***acted upon, treated***), with allusions to ***being in time*** (as with successfully running to ***catch** a bus*, CF ***catch up with***). Early / timely treatment massively increases the chances of *successful* treatment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sense is 'be in a position to deal with it'. Oxford Languages doesn't give this exact sense, but it's related to *catch a bus* (be there in time to board it) or *reach or be in a place in time to see (a person, performance, programme, etc.). -
"she was hurrying downstairs to catch the news"* Obviously it's easier to treat cancer if it's detected early.

Comment: Better to catch a fire early, while it is just a sheet of paper in the trash, and has not yet spread to the whole house.